# pointwise limit of sequence of Lipschitz continuous functions is Lipschitz continuous $\Rightarrow$ Lipschitz constants bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, lipschitz-functions, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

A sequence $\{ f_n\}$ of Lipschitz continuous functions (with corresponding Lipschitz constants $M_n$) has pointwise limit $f$ which is also Lipschitz continuous (with Lipschitz constant $M$). Is it true that the sequence $\{ M_n\}$ is bounded? And if not, under what extra assumptions is it true?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f_n(t)=\sin(n^2t)/n$.